# NVM & Node.js - Recommended install for all users

Tags: node.js, nvm

is there a recommended install for nvm so all users can use it? i cannot find anything on the web regarding this.

this is what i did

- installed nvm in a common directory
- put the nvm.sh script locationin .profile for all users
- created a nvm/alias directory (nvm complains if this is not here for other users)

then each user must either run "nvm use " or put it in their profile by default

not sure if there is a better way?

thanks

Answer (score 58):

Here is what I did:

1. Installed `nvm` in `/opt/nvm` as root. Seemed like an appropriate location.

   ```
   # git clone git@github.com:creationix/nvm.git /opt/nvm
   ```
2. Created the directory `/usr/local/nvm`. This is where the downloads will go (`$NVM_DIR`)

   ```
   # mkdir /usr/local/nvm
   ```
3. Create the directory `/usr/local/node`. This is where the NPM global stuff will go:

   ```
   # mkdir /usr/local/node
   ```
4. Created a file called `nvm.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` with the following contents:

   ```
   export NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm
   source /opt/nvm/nvm.sh

   export NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/usr/local/node
   export PATH="/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH"
   ```
5. Re-login to a shell session, then set the default node version.

   ```
   # nvm install 0.10
   # nvm alias default 0.10
   ```

The node binaries should now be in the `PATH` for all users the next time you login to a shell session. NPM will install global things to the `/usr/local/node` prefix.

Comment: Great setup - however NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX isn't being respected when I follow this setup and global modules are being installed in nvm against the current node version. Any ideas?

Comment: I miss a step 4.5: `source /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh`. Only then nvm is available to me.

Comment: @czerasz you shouldn't have to do that; try logging in again? I ran into that too but it went away after I logged out/in

Comment: I did this but for some reason when I try to install it tells me that I don't have permission. So I try it with sudo and it says it can't find nvm.

Comment: @jcollum I agree that re-logging is a nice way to enable nvm. but when you need to install NVM and do something with it in one script then you need to load it manually.

Comment: not required in recent version:
step3 and 
in the file:

export NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/usr/local/node

Comment: I tried following these instructions. When I ran `nvm install node` i get the following error `nvm is not compatible with the "NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX" environment variable: currently set to "/usr/local/node"`

Comment: @TechPro I'm getting that too: `nvm is not compatible with the "NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX" environment variable: currently set to "/usr/local/node"; Run `unset NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX` to unset it`  .. I wonder if unsetting that is wise.

Comment: `nvm` maintainer here. `nvm` is NOT COMPATIBLE with the "prefix" option, and you should NOT EVER install `nvm` as root. `nvm` is per-user. If you want to share node across users, `nvm` is the wrong tool to use.

Comment: I think comment from @LJHarb need more attention here. He is the maintainer of the nvm afterall. Maybe you should post that comment as answer?

Comment: @LJHarb is it still true in 2019?

Comment: Yes, it will be true forever. There's no reason to use the "prefix" option at all anyways, and nvm can't possibly ever be compatible with it.

Comment: @LJHarb great man lesson learned here - ready the comments first !!

Comment: Installing a utility like this at the system level for all users removes the option for each user to choose which version of the utility they wish to run. It's common to create an application based on specific versions of tools, libraries, etc.. This creates the opportunity to test new versions of dependencies and help ensure that bugs or security issues are not introduced when upgrading.

Answer (score 55):

It's best to install one copy of node globally so that other users can access it. To do this, run the following command (entering your user's password at the prompt):

```
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

This commend is copying whatever version of node you have active via nvm into the `/usr/local/` directory and setting the permissions so that all users can access them.

To check that it works, become the root user and do another which command to make sure that node is now installed to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo -s
which node
```

If you ever want to change the version of node that's installed system wide, just do another nvm use vXX.XX.XX to switch your user's node to the version you want, and then re-run the first command above to copy it to the system directory.

Comment: Please credit sources: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps

Comment: this broke a lot of permissions for myself, just a fyi

Comment: This is most certainly not "best". It may be "convenient" but also the opposite of best if you need to run multiple versions of node under different user accounts. Using `nvm` (_never_ installed as root) is the only easily applied option there.

Comment: I'm getting an `cp: cannot stat '/{bin,lib,share}': No such file or directory` error here, on ubuntu debian.  Any ideas for me?

Comment: This command can break your sudo. Strongly reconsider using this

Comment: Why this command will break sudo? Anyone? I'm interesting in doing the same in VPS

Comment: I think this "breaks sudo" (so to speak) if `which node` returns nothing, hence `$n` will be empty, hence `chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*` will set permissions for `/bin/`, including `/bin/sudo`, which is obviously not what we want. This solution only works if you already installed node.

Answer (score 32):

1. Login as root: `sudo -s`
2. Create destination folder: `mkdir /usr/local/nvm`
3. Install nvm:
   `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh |   NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm bash`
4. Create a file called `nvm.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` with the following contents:

   ```bash
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   export NVM_DIR="/usr/local/nvm"
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
   ```
5. Set permissions `chmod 755 /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh`
6. Run `/etc/profile.d/nvm.sh`
7. Install node: `nvm install node`
8. Optionally update npm with: `npm install -g npm`

Comment: Didn't work for me. I think some steps are missing here.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine for me on CentOS 7!
Thank you!

Comment: I had to create "/usr/local/nvm" first and also "chmod 755 /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh"

Comment: I had to create "/usr/local/nvm" first and also "chmod 755 /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh" 
"Run /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh" looks like "cd /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh" followed by "./nvm.sh" 
and also had to log out and back in for the nvm commands to work.

Answer (score 11):

Install NVM on your Linux server, after that install node version using NVM (run all the command as root user). After that run the below command for all the users get nodejs available with nvm

```
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

The above command is a bit complicated, but all it’s doing is copying whatever version of node you have active via nvm into the /usr/local/ directory (where user installed global files should live on a linux VPS/server) and setting the permissions so that all users can access them.

/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/**bin/node**

Switch the user name check your node version.

```
su - username
which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: This command can break your sudo. Strongly reconsider using this as if you don't have a root account you will be in for a world of pain

Answer (score 6):

Since LJHarb recommends not installing this globally, I decided to create a script to install nvm when you login to the server. I needed this as I had several users setup that *may* login, but needed access to pm2 (to monitor one of our applications).

Create the script in /etc/profile.d/ (named nvm.sh for example):

```
#!/bin/bash
NODE_VER=6.2.2
if [ ! -f ~/.nvm/nvm.sh ]; then
    # May need to be updated with the latest nvm release
    wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash
fi
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
if ! command -v node | grep -q $NODE_VER; then
    echo "Node is not installed"
    nvm install $NODE_VER
    nvm alias default $NODE_VER
fi
```

For our application, we needed pm2 shared between users:

```
if ! command -v pm2 &>/dev/null; then
    echo "pm2 not installed"
    npm install -g pm2
fi
# Share pm2 configuration between users
alias pm2='env HOME=/opt/sora pm2'
```

Comment: You might want to add NVM_DIR="" to the beginning too. If you don't, then 'su-ing' into another user will cause the install to fail. This is because NVM_DIR is used by the install script, but not initially set before it's used. So it has the value set, which might actually be the previous user.

Answer (score 1):

I had a small VPS with two users, wanted to avoid installing multiple copies of node due to limited space

Simply moved `$HOME/.nvm` of user that had NVM to `/opt/nvm` and `chmod -R 777 /opt/nvm` so writable by all users

Then set each user's `NVM_HOME` in `.bashrc` to `/opt/nvm`

Seemed like most obvious solution to me, since one user had a pre-existing .nvm folder

Re: ugly permissions, this copy will only be used for development purposes - I would def recommend anyone using node in production not consider this method

Answer (score 1):

I found a cleaner way, and this way you can probably have multiple versions with tweaks, I haven't tried it.

Login to your root account and follow these steps.

1. install nvm
2. install node with it, eg:

```bash
nvm install 14
```

3. run

```bash
n=$(which node);
n=${n%/bin/node};cd $n;cd ..;
ls
```

4. pick a version and run it in :

```bash
node_v=the_version_you_picked
```

5. run

```bash
mv $node_v /usr/local/node/$node_v;cd /usr/local/node/$node_v;chmod -R 755 ./

echo "PATH=\${PATH}:/usr/local/node/$node_v/bin;export PATH" > /etc/profile.d/gloabl_node.sh
```

and exit and re-login, now run `which node` or `node -v` to confirm it's working.

Now you can rename the bin files and all the other configs it needs to run multiple versions. eg: rename `node` -> `node-14` and so on.

Comment: `mkdir /usr/local/node/`