# sudo: npm: command not found

Tags: node.js, linux, unix, npm

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version of node. I'm following the instructions at http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs

But when I do:

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

I get the error:

```
sudo: npm: command not found
```

npm works without sudo. When I do:

```
whereis node
```

I see:

```
node: /usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node /usr/bin/X11/node /usr/local/node
```

Running:

```
which npm
```

Shows:

```
/usr/local/node/bin/npm
```

I tried the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5062718/1246159

But I'm still getting the same error. I also looked at the `/etc/sudoers` file and the relevant line is:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

This looks fine to me. How can I possibly get NPM working with sudo command?

Comment: What does `whereis npm` say?

Comment: it says: npm: /usr/bin/npm /usr/bin/X11/npm

Comment: Does this work? `sudo /usr/bin/npm install -g n`

Comment: nope, says command not found

Comment: I wonder if the shebang line (the line starting with `#!`) of `/usr/bin/npm` might be faulty, what does that say?

Comment: actually there was a link to the npm at  /usr/bin/npm. I deleted is. Now where i run whereis npm, it simply says "npm:" and no path! But npm command still works but not as sudo....

Comment: Try `which npm` then.

Comment: Can you try reinstalling node?  It sounds like you deleted npm.

Comment: Which npm returns "/usr/local/node/bin/npm"

Comment: @JeffSloyer npm command still working though....

Comment: You may have added `/usr/local/node/bin` to your `$PATH`, but `npm` should be installed in `/usr/local/bin`. The first directory isn't in `secure_path` which explains why `sudo` can't find it.

Comment: Using `nvm` on Ubuntu here - with @robertklep comment, I tried `sudo /home/${user}/.nvm/version/node/${version}/bin/npm install` and it worked.

Comment: It solved my problem by reinstalling from following package. https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: check in the bottom of [official doc](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation)  where it says _To create a sudo link:_

Comment: I tried `nvm use 16` (for node version 16)  and then npm commands started working again.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

The npm file should be in `/usr/local/bin/npm`. If it's not there, install node.js again with the package on their [website](https://nodejs.org/). This worked in my case.

Comment: thx.
If you install node in other data drives, where os is not installed, you can not find this path.

Comment: in the case of mac os with homebrew.. two steps to do is to (1)  which node (2) which npm which should be both in /usr/local/bin (where homebrew installs/symlinks node+npm)... to resolve.. try (1) brew doctor (2) brew reinstall node

if its still giving issues.. check your path (echo $PATH). you must have multiple bin locations that point to various node installations..if that is the case...  cleanup (as in make it neater) your ~/.bashrc / ~/.bash_profile, so /usr/local/bin is there loaded without another one pointing to a random node installation.

Comment: This is a partial solution. The issue occurs when you manually install node. You must softlink each installed binary into /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin. Setting the path in root's bashrc will not work as it is not read during sudo therefore this is the only way it seems unless you install package.

Comment: as @shrimpwagon said, the bottom of manual instructions tell you to link "sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin/node /usr/bin/node

sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm

sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin/npx /usr/bin/npx"

Comment: Why shoudl I use THEIR website?

Comment: getting it from the main website and add it to the PATH was the easiest way to handle this, the npm version from apt is an old one (you can add a point before the node folder to hide it in the file explorer)

Answer (score 349):

I had to do

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

that worked for me.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to express.

Comment: This is out of date. What worked for me was these commands I found in here: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall



# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs

Comment: according to the https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node website this is still the supported way of installing/updating npm.   If npm didnt get installed via nodejs which it didnt for some reason on my system.  this is an accepted way of installing npm seperately.  It is still compatible with the current version of nodejs.   However if you are worried about the package being out of date you can download whatever version you wish with this https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-{VERSION}.tgz link

Comment: @tinysunlight  Im not sure what is unclear.  The op says the npm command is missing.  This command installs the npm command.

Comment: This is not the correct answer to the question because it is obvious from the op that `npm` is already installed but not reachable when invoked through sudo. With this solution you reinstall npm which is already existing. This is fighting symptoms rather than finding the cause. I understand that this might correct broken things for some people, but it is misleading, standing like this.

Comment: For me the solution was this post: [On EC2: sudo node command not found, but node without sudo is ok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976658/on-ec2-sudo-node-command-not-found-but-node-without-sudo-is-ok)

Comment: This worked for me on 1.10.2018. I had Node 8.9.4 installed and working but I was getting the same error with NPM as the OP. Installed NPM again per this answer and the problem was solved.

Comment: When I installed node using NVM on Ubuntu 18.10, sudo doesn't recognize npm as a command. `sudo apt-get install npm` worked for me.

Comment: This is the only athorized version of installation. If it does not work it means npm ins not a part of distribution. You shlud consider carefully if You want use such software

Answer (score 139):

For MAC users, the follow steps worked for me.

If you get Error for Brew, Here's the command you need to type first in the terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Then run following commands:

```
$ brew update
$ brew uninstall node
$ brew install node
$ brew postinstall
```

Comment: The `brew uninstall node` did not work for me, but I carried on with the `brew install node` and `brew postinstall` and it fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: What does `brew postinstall` do exactly?

Comment: in Homebrew version 2.2.14 `brew postinstall` is redundant

Comment: In my case, `brew install node` was unable to overwrite the symlink of an older version. I had to run `brew link --overwrite node` which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 93):

I had the same problem; here are the commands to fix it:

- `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node`
- `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node /usr/lib/node`
- `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm`
- `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node-waf /usr/bin/node-waf`

Comment: Worked for me on CentOS 7

Comment: Worked for me Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I use NVM so the first path was to where NVM installed node and npm (the path includes a version `%HOME%/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/bin/npm`). Unfortunate that I will have to reference this answer each time I update using NVM due to how the version in the path will change

Comment: This solved it for me as well! Originally posted on Stack Overflow: [On EC2: sudo node command not found, but node without sudo is ok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976658/on-ec2-sudo-node-command-not-found-but-node-without-sudo-is-ok)

Comment: @kas
`sudo ln -s $(whereis node) /usr/bin/node`

And so on. in your bash profile.

Comment: Worked for me in AWS ec2 instance.

Comment: I preferred this way instead of installing node again (I'm using binaries)

Comment: I installed node using nvm and these two following commands worked for me.
sudo ln -s ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node /usr/bin/node && 
sudo ln -s ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm

Comment: Copy and paste these commands won't fix it for some users like I who did not put nodejs in `/usr/local/bin/node` but rather you should point out out that we should link node or npm binaries found inside `bin` folder of nodejs folder(which can be somewhere like in `/usr/local/node-v14.17.0-linux-x64` or anywhere you extracted your nodejs folder). In my  case bin folder containing `node` and `npm` binaries is found in  `/usr/local/node-v14.17.0-linux-x64` .

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73308302/6243352) seems to be an improved version of this.

Comment: This is terrible advice. You should not mess with `/usr/bin` (or `/usr/lib` etc) at all on modern systems. You can create symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` (or `/usr/local/lib` etc) if you like; though then of course make sure `/usr/local/bin` is on your `PATH`.

Answer (score 34):

## ** EDIT **

WARNING! - Doing a `chmod 777` is a fairly radical solution. Try these first, one at a time, and stop when one works:

- `$ sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm`
- `$ sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
- `$ sudo chmod g+w /usr/local/lib`
- `$ sudo chmod g+rwx /usr/local/lib`

---

`$ brew postinstall node` is the only install part where I would get a problem

```
Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/.github
```

So I

```
// !! READ EDIT ABOVE BEFORE RUNNING THIS CODE !!
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib
$ brew postinstall node
```

and viola, npm is now linked

```
$ npm -v
3.10.10
```

---

**Extra**

If you used `-R 777` on **lib** my recommendation would be to set nested files and directories to a default setting:

- $ `find /usr/local/lib -type f -print -exec chmod 644 {} \;`
- $ `find /usr/local/lib -type d -print -exec chmod 755 {} \;`
- $ `chmod /usr/local/lib 755`

Comment: @Jacksonkr .....did you just recommended chmoding 777 the entire local/lib folder?

Comment: What `chmod` should this directory be?

Comment: @tim_xyz `drwxr-xr-x` are the defaults for lib. That said, do NOT use the recursive feature `-R` when setting the folder back.

Comment: Thanks! sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/node_modules worked for me

Comment: Don't ever `chmod 777` unless you have a damned good reason to.

Comment: @TimothyPulliam You're absolutely correct. I purposefully put a warning at the top of the answer for that reason.

Answer (score 23):

I had to do the following:

1. `brew update`
2. `brew uninstall node`
3. Visit https://nodejs.org/en/ download the file
4. Install the downloaded file

Answer (score 16):

If you installed node/npm with nvm, the nvm environment configuration file has to be run before you can use either package.

This is generally found in ~/.nvm/nvm.sh.

To run this automatically, include:

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

in the .bash_profile file for your user

If you then want to use sudo with that user, make sure to include the -i parameter to make sudo set the user environment. eg

```
sudo -iu jenkins npm install grunt-cli
```

Answer (score 13):

You can make symbolic link & its works.

1. find path of current `npm`

> `which npm`

2. make symbolic link by following command

> `sudo ln -s **which/npm** /usr/local/bin/npm`

3. Test and verify.

> `sudo npm -v`

Comment: the simplest solution, worked perfect for me, just had to do the same with node

Comment: @dipenparmar12 I tried the same, but now I'm getting /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: Not a directory

Comment: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/bin/npm: No such file or directory

Answer (score 11):

On macOS, this worked for me:

```
brew reinstall node
```

Comment: Sorry just noticed the question is tagged with `unix`, but it might still be helpful since it's the top Google search result for "macos npm command not found"

Answer (score 10):

In order to install npm packages globally with sudo permission, `/usr/bin/npm` should be available. If `npm` exists on some other directory, create a soft link like:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

It works on Fedora 25, node8.0.0 and npm5.0.0

Comment: Simple and effective, worked for me on linux mint 20.

Comment: This should be the best answer! Thanks dude it worked for me

Comment: This worked on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This is bad advice. You should not mess with `/usr/bin` on modern platforms. The proper fix in this scenario is to add `/usr/local/bin` to the `PATH` of `sudo`

Answer (score 10):

You can resolve this by creating symbolic links for npm and node which is quick and simple:

```
sudo ln -s $(which npm) /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```

I'm using `which` to get the location and then passing that in as a variable to the command e.g. `$(which npm)`.

I'm creating a symbolic link for node as well because npm depends on
node.

Then you can just:

```
sudo npm -v
```

No need to reinstall node or go wild with chmod on whole directories.

Comment: This gives:  ln: /usr/local/bin/node: File exists

Answer (score 8):

For CentOS users, this works for me:

```
sudo yum install npm
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that in Fedora for example, it is very outdated in dnf / yum repos

Comment: On CentOS 7 you need to enable EPEL repo first: `yum install epel-release; yum install npm`

Answer (score 7):

For debian after installing node
enter

```
curl -k -O -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh    
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node  
sh install.sh
```

Comment: Also solved on Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: You should not mess with `/usr/bin`. You can `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node` if you like, though. But I think this has been fixed in more recent Debian versions.

Answer (score 5):

simply reinstall .

On RHEL, CentOS and Fedora

```
sudo yum remove nodejs npm
sudo dnf remove nodejs npm   [On Fedora 22+ versions]
```

then

```
yum -y install nodejs npm
dnf -y install nodejs npm   [On Fedora 22+ versions]
```

easy!..
both node and npm works like a charm now!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by

```
apt-get install npm2deb
```

Comment: what is this answer? npm2deb is a 3rd party

Comment: it's not entirely "trusted" as in 3rd party can be more likely compromised than from npm directly from the source. i don't know anything about npm2deb but think about if you wanted to use it at your company, they'd probably be strict about auditing it

Answer (score 2):

**My solution is:**

```
sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" n stable
```

Works fine for me.

Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400598/861615

This happens because you have change default global packages directory

Comment: This is the only answer that doesn't introduce tons of other problems (like having two installations, messing up permissions, etc etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Work for me [Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to use a different directory. In this example, you will create and use hidden directory in your home directory.

Back up your computer.
On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

```sh
 mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```sh
 npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

```sh
 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

On the command line, update your system variables:

```sh
 source ~/.profile
```

To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:

```sh
 npm install -g jshint
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded node package and extracted somewhere like `/opt` you can simply create symbolic link inside `/usr/local/bin`.

```
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /opt/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/npm
/usr/local/bin/node -> /opt/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/node
```

Answer (score 1):

So, for those using:

**NVM and homebrew**

make sure to set node version. For me, my node version was no longer set. So, I checked what versions I had using

`nvm ls`

this listed v16.13.1, so I set it to use this

`nvm use 16`

once my node version was set, npm commands worked again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,the reason for it was npm package manager was not installed while installing node. This was caused because of the following mistake: 
In the installation process there is a step called "Custom Setup", here you have the option to choose one of the following: 
1) Node.js runtime (This is selected by default). 
2) npm package manager
3) Online documentation shortcuts. 
4) Add to Path. 
If you proceed as it is npm package manager will not be installed and hence you will get the error.

Solution: 
Select npm package manager when you get these options. 
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Appended npm binary path to sudo path using visudo and editing "secure_path"

Now "sudo npm" works

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue in Homestead and tried many ways.
I tried with

sudo apt-get install nodejs

I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Finally I tried with**

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

It worked fine.

```
root@homestead:/usr/local/bin# npm -v
3.10.10

root@homestead:/usr/local/bin# node -v
v6.13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have installed node.js using .tar file available on node.js,
I had to put the location of the node directory on:

> ~/.bashrc

of root by changing from normal user to root using command:

> sudo -i

then I had to add the path to node where I extracted it into .bashrc file as below:
[image]

then refereshed .bashrc using

> . ~/.bashrc

there after

```
npm: command not found
```

went away

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Installing node again which seems like the accepted solution, The Problem is there are no permissions to the nodejs folder/usr/local.

Enter the following command `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/nodejs/`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for some reason after installing some python modules, I suddenly start getting messages saying `node` is not installed or is not recognized as a command.
Upon checking, my path is registered in `.bashrc`.
So, I sourced that file, and everything started working again.

`source .bashrc`

Answer (score -1):

Remove Node completely:

```
  brew uninstall --force node
```

Install again:

```
brew install node;
which node # => /usr/local/bin/node
export NODE_PATH='/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
```

Answer (score -1):

In case could be useful for anyone that uses `rh-*` packages this worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/rh/rh-nodejs8/root/usr/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using linux delete node_modules folder that exists in /usr/lib

```
sudo rm -rf node-modules
```

then reinstall node using curl:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install curl build-essential
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt install -y nodejs
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score -3):

My workaround was to login as root and now I don't have to use sudo again

```
su root
```

Answer (score -15):

Installl node.js & simply run

```
npm install -g bower
```

from your project dir