# Npm command not found on Intel Galileo gen 2 - linux 3.8.7 standard

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, intel, intel-galileo

Im working with Intel Galileo gen 2 board with Linux galileo 3.8.7-yocto-standard image, but i cant use npm command here. When I type

```
npm -v
npm: command not found
```

I have also tried:

```
which npm
```

But I dont see anything so I think npm is not installed?
When i type for node version:

```
node -v
v4.4.3
```

How can I install npm module (without apt-get -> image dont support that too)? Anyone had the same issues? Thanks for your advices....

Comment: Tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34558299/2703418 ?

Comment: i need to do it without apt-get cause the image dont support this command

Comment: What do you mean with 'the image'? What OS or distribution are you on?

Comment: Linux galileo 3.8.7-yocto-standard

Answer (score 1):

when you install nodejs inside Galileo board, for instance, assume you use **opkg**:

*opkg install nodejs*

Then npm should be install along with nodejs by default as a "dependence"

From website https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm:

> **npm is distributed with Node.js- which means that when you download**
>   **Node.js, you automatically get npm installed on your computer.**