# sudo: npm: command not found while installing Azure Cli

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install Azure CLi on  my ubuntu 14.04 with command.

> sudo npm install azure-cli -g

But it showing

> sudo: npm: command not found

---

My npm configurations are.

npm version.

> npm -v

```
3.10.5
```

> which npm

```
/home/stack/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/npm
```

I don't know why it occurs.Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo: npm: command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472755/sudo-npm-command-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be easily fixed by reinstalling Node js.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to `npm` as `sudo`er, because of You have not installed `nodejs, npm` system-wide.

I don't see reason to use `nvm`.

Why not just install `nodejs` and `npm` as usualy.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Or compile from sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install make g++ gcc libssl-dev git
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.5.0/node-v4.5.0.tar.gz
tar -zxf node-v4.5.0.tar.gz
cd node-v4.5.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```