# EC2 - Codedeploy NPM Not Found Error

Tags: linux, bash, unix, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to run an `AfterInstall` hook in my Codedeploy deployment that runs a shell script to cd into the directory of my application give the user write privileges and then run `npm install` to install application dependencies, but I receive the following error during deployment

```
Error CodeScriptFailed
Script Namescripts/npm-start.sh
MessageScript at specified location: scripts/npm-start.sh run as user root failed with exit code 127
Log TailLifecycleEvent - ApplicationStart
Script - scripts/npm-start.sh
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/dfdfdfd-c90-9f39-4ab9-bd51-e3f737003a72/d-ZID6SUV6U/deployment-archive/scripts/npm-start.sh: line 3: npm: command not found
```

Now I have run into issues in the past where running as sudo or root with `npm` will cause issues because it is installed with my `ubuntu` user, but even when I use `runas: ubuntu` in my `appspec.yml` it runs as user root.

Anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

**appspec.yml**:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/app/
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/npm-install.sh
      runas: root
      timeout: 300
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/npm-start.sh
      runas: root
      timeout: 60
```

**npm-install.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/app
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/app
sudo chmod o-rwx /var/www/app
npm install
```

**npm-start.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/app
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that `npm` is properly installed and set up on your box? In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472755/sudo-npm-command-not-found) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404929/node-command-not-found), you can see users having a similar issues. It sounds like you'll need to re-install NodeJS to get NPM happy again.

You should log onto your box, and try running `sudo npm install` yourself. If it works in that scenario, you should check your `.bash*` files to see if you do anything to put `npm` in your path or something that might impact how it runs. If you can confirm that your setup is ok in non-CodeDeploy scenarios, you could debug the CodeDeploy scenario specifically, but I'm guessing it's your setup.