# NPM command can't work it will pop out Permission denied

Tags: npm-install

I'm try to check on terminal

```
 hauying@hauying-yoga-linux:~$ npm -v
 bash: /usr/bin/npm: Permission denied
```

and I try add sudo

```
 hauying@hauying-yoga-linux:~$ sudo npm -v
 sudo: npm: command not found
```

and i find name

```
 hauying@hauying-yoga-linux:~$ find -name npm
 ./npm
```

I try this commeand

```
 hauying@hauying-yoga-linux:~$ whereis npm
 npm: /usr/bin/npm /usr/share/npm /usr/share/man/man1/npm.1.gz 
 /usr/share/man/man3/npm.3.gz
```

someone can help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472755/sudo-npm-command-not-found

Comment: I have find npm in the "/usr/bin " this file and i will try "sudo apt-get install npm" 
  this command pop "Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  npm is already the newest version (1.4.21+ds-2).
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
"

Comment: but doesn't work too