# Mac error: /bin/sh: npm: command not found

Tags: node.js, macos, makefile, cmake

I am trying to build c++ project and see below error:
Would you please take a look?

```
/bin/sh: npm: command not found
make[2]: *** [modules/GUI/CMakeFiles/Client] Error 127
make[1]: *** [modules/GUI/CMakeFiles/Client.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I followed this wiki: [sudo: npm: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472755/sudo-npm-command-not-found)
But it doesn't work for me.

```
For MAC users, the follow steps worked for me, the error still there.

$ brew update
$ brew uninstall node
$ brew install node
$ brew postinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see [this](https://changelog.com/posts/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x)?

Have you tried: `brew doctor`?

What do you get when you do:

```
which node
which npm
```

If you get anything for `node`, look for the path and see what is nearby.

Worst case scenario, if you have not added anything else to `brew`, consider removing `brew` and reinstalling.

FYI:  For me, using nvm, I see this:

```
➜  ~ which npm
/Users/pgkehle/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin/npm
➜  ~ which node
/Users/pgkehle/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin/node
```

Your path will be different, but consider `nvm` as an alternative.