# Unable to view the React app started with 'sudo npm start'

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

- I need to run my local React app at `banker-dev.mh*b.my` on port number 443.
- This is to enable the app to call a third party API
- I've set my local .env file with the following:

  `HTTPS=true`

  `HOST=banker-dev.mh*b.my`

  `PORT=443`
- When I run `npm start`, I encountered the message:

`? Admin permissions are required to run a server on a port below 1024.`
`Would you like to run the app on another port instead? (Y/n)`

- So I tried `sudo npm start` but hit error `sudo: npm: command not found`
- I then sudo installed npm by referring to this: [sudo: npm: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472755/sudo-npm-command-not-found)
- Now I'm able to run `sudo npm start`
- The app is started as I can see from the code editor.
- But it's not opening a new browser window with the app loading as it usually does with my normal `npm start`
- And I noticed a weird thing: it's trying to bind to the host `dev.mh*b.my` instead of `banker-dev.mh*b.my`
  [image]
- My hosts file contains the following:

  `127.0.0.1       localhost`

  `127.0.1.1       yogesnsamy-ThinkPad-E490s`

  `127.0.0.1       banker-dev.mh*b.my`

  `127.0.0.1       dev.mh*b.my`
- I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. I'm attaching a video reference of what's happening: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TYcX3wG8yBFjSukvVAkYZDloPJE3JS8T/view?usp=sharing
  Sorry that part where the app starts to load takes long (0:34 to 1:00). After it does, I try to view the app on the browser but fail.