# Running a script to connect through ssh then run npm install pm2 results in: 'npm: command not found'

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ssh, sh

I'm running this command from my local machine:

```
ssh -tt -i "pem.pem" ec2-user@ec2-IPADDRESS.compute-1.amazonaws.com "sudo su -c 'cd /dir/;npm install pm2'"
```

It connects, operates as a super users, cds to dir and attempts to run the command but returns that npm is not a command recognized by the system.

However, when I connect "manually" i.e.

```
ssh -i "pem.pem" ec2-user@ec2-IPADDRESS.compute-1.amazonaws.com
sudo su
cd /dir
npm install pm2
```

it works.

npm is installed under root and the system can see it.

```
ssh -tt -i "pem.pem" ec2-user@ec2-IPADDRESS.compute-1.amazonaws.com "sudo su -c 'cd /dir/;whoami'"
```

and

```
ssh -i "pem.pem" ec2-user@ec2-IPADDRESS.compute-1.amazonaws.com
sudo su
cd /dir
whoami
```

both return "root"

Why can't the npm command be found when running on top of an ssh?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/31734090/667820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you login, you create an interactive shell, which typically will read a couple of files, including `/etc/profile`, `$HOME/.profile`, and `$HOME/.bashrc` in the case of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

Any of these files can add extra elements (paths) to the `PATH` variable, which affects which commands can be found.

When you run the command line directly, no such initialisation takes place, and the value of `$PATH` may be limited to just `/bin:/usr/bin`.

Next there is `sudo`, which may or may not import the value of `PATH` when looking for commands.

**Solution**

Best you can do is find out where `npm` is installed, and use its full PATH.