# sudo: yarn: command not found , create-react-app: command not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, ubuntu-18.04

I was trying to install react . I found there are two ways of doing it either through npm or through yarn . I am using Ubuntu 18.04 . I have installed node and npm .

```
name@admin-desktop:~$ node -v
v16.14.0
name@admin-desktop:~$ npm -v
8.3.1
```

After that I have installed yarn via npm through following commands :

```
npm install --global yarn
name@admin-desktop:~$ yarn --version
1.22.19
```

after that I gave following command :

```
yarn global add create-react-app@1.5.2
```

it gave following output:

```
yarn global v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning create-react-app > tar-pack > tar@2.2.2: This 
version of tar is no longer supported, and will not 
receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "create-react-app@1.5.2" with binaries:
      - create-react-app
Done in 3.53s.
```

then I gave following command :

```
name@admin-desktop:~$ create-react-app --help
create-react-app: command not found
```

May I know why this is creating a problem when it successfully installed ?

I also tried to install react through npm but it again created problem so I tried to seek help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472755/sudo-npm-command-not-found) when sudo npm install -g was not working so I gave command `which npm` and it resulted in `/home/name/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/npm`

after that I gave command :

```
sudo ln -s /home/name/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/npm 
/usr/bin/npm
```

After that I again tried to install react but again got error :

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app@1.5.2
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

How to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 1):

just do the following steps and the problem is solved:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

npx create-react-app@latest my-app-name
```

you don't need to install create-react-app globaly anymore

Comment: How can you use create-react-app without installing it ?

Comment: npx will handle it for you https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

Comment: one more question what if I don't add @latest in upper command ? will it take latest version by-default ?

Comment: yeah its not required

Comment: I am thankful that you have suggested a way to proceed but I'm still expecting if someone could point out what went wrong in my  approach so your response definitely provided a solution to me but it didn't resolve my query that's why I up-voted but didn't accept it as my answer .