# AWS AutoScaling Group Node.js Server Unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-auto-scaling

I'm trying to configure an EC2 instance Node.js web server that can use AutoScaling and LoadBalancer to adapt the server according to demand.

I have made an AMI of an EC2 instance that when manually used to create a new EC2 instance will be publicly available upon initialization without any further configuration.

I can make several of these instances manually and put them behind a LoadBalancer and it will show their status as being healthy.

I can use an AutoScaling Group to spin up multiple instances that are each publicly accessible.

I can manually place the instances generated by the AutoScaling Group into the Target Group associated with the LoadBalancer and it will show their status as being healthy.

However, when I attach a new AutoScaling Group to the LoadBalancer it creates new instances, but those instances register as 'unhealthy' in the Target Group.

Based on my other successes it seems like this is a problem with getting the AutoScaling Group and LoadBalancer to interface with each other.

UPDATE: It turns out the problem isn't to do with the combination of LoadBalancer and AutoScaling Group, there was a confounding factor with whether or or not the instances have a public IP address. The instances without a publicly accessible IP address (either with a public IP address in a private subnet or just without a public IP address at all) are registering as unhealthy. I'm not sure what this means, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I was using the curl request from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350634/how-to-yum-install-node-js-on-amazon-linux) in my User Data bash script and my some of the instances weren't able to make the request due to routing configurations, therefore Node.js wasn't actually being installed on those devices and wasn't able to respond to requests