# Install node in Amazon Linux 2

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-lightsail, amazon-linux

I purchased Amazon Linux 2 machine using AWS LightSail and tried to install node on that machine. But after several tries I can't able to install node and got the error shared below.

```
[root@ip-my public ip /]# sudo yum install nodejs
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 2:18.3.0-1nodesource will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: 2:nodejs-18.3.0-1nodesource.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: 2:nodejs-18.3.0-1nodesource.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.3.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.3.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35165401/12594882) might help

Comment: @medbenzekri thanks for the help, but I got the same error

Comment: Got the same error today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think AWS LightSail Amazon Linux 2 supports node version <=16.x,
So we want to install node version <=16, I installed node version 16 and it works!!

Here are the steps followed,

**Step 1:- Configure Yum Repository**

```
$ sudo yum install -y gcc-c++ make 
$ curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
```

**Step 2:– Install Node.js on Amazon Linux**

```
$ sudo yum install -y nodejs
```

**Step 3 – Check Version**

```
$ node -v  
$ npm -v
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74298148

Comment: And [AWS docs: setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html)

Comment: "Amazon Linux 2 does not currently support the current LTS release (version 18.x) of Node.js" :(

Answer (score 10):

My solution to fix this problem, you must erase cache with this command:

```
sudo rm -R /var/cache/yum/x86_64/2/nodesource/
```

Now, you can download the correct version:

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
```

And now you can install:

```
sudo yum install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Removing the cache was the solution for me