GLIBC version issue while installing npm on Amazon Linux 2023
I am using Amazon Linux 2023 and trying to update Node from v14 to v18. While running the command nvm install 18.13.0 it's installing the Node properly. However, right after that I tried to run the command npm i -g npm@10.2.4 and it showed the following list of errors -
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)

I have been trying different versions of Node (> v16) but the same thing is happening. When I tried to check the current version of GLIBC on my Linux (ldd --version) it said 2.34. I'm utterly clueless at this point and need help!

Not an exact duplicate, but basically the same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/q/72022527/2422776. Long story short, you either need a newer Linux version or an older Node.js version.

@Mureinik I already have the latest version of Linux (Amazon Linux 2023) which should support up to Node v20 as per this document - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html#runtimes-supported
Also it shows the available GLIBC version on my Linux is 2.34. Also, I'm actually not looking for downgrading the Node.js version.
