# Why installed Node.js and Yarn is lost after reconnect to EC2 linux instance

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have on `AWS EC2` instance. When I install `Node.js` with this
[AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html) all works fine until i logout current session and log in, than `Node.js` and `Yarn` are gone. There is also note from `AWS`:

> The node installation only applies to the current Amazon EC2 session. If you restart your CLI session you need to use nvm to enable the installed node version. If the instance is terminated, you need to install node again. The alternative is to make an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) of the Amazon EC2 instance once you have the configuration that you want to keep, as described in the following topic.

Is it possible to install `Node.js` so it is available in another session? I installed zsh and that works for all sessions.

I also created simple script that will install `Node.js` and `Yarn`. Commands in this script are from `AWS` Tutorial page that I mentioned early. It will install `Node.js` and `Yarn`, show that all works (it shows `Yarn` version and message from node command), but when I type `npm --version` or `yarn --version` it will shows message zsh: *command not found: yarn* (or similar message for npm).

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash

. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

nvm install --lts

node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

echo "installing YARN !!!!! "

npm install yarn --global
```

Why is my script not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use manual from AWS how to install Node.js than instalation is only made in your home directory that lives only for current session. To install Node.js and Yarn I used this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35165401/78935

Or you could simply use this:

```
sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash
sudo yum -y install nodejs
sudo npm install yarn --global
yarn --version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this method, which reduces cache size and runtime.

```
name: CI cache advance
    
    on:
      push:
        branches: [ "main" ]
    
    jobs:
      ci:
        name: Running CI
        runs-on: self-hosted
        steps:
          - name: Checkout code
            uses: actions/checkout@v3.0.2
    
          - name: Setup Node.js
            uses: actions/setup-node@v3.1.1
            with:
              node-version: v16.14.2
    
          - name: Get node version
            id: node
            run: |
              echo "::set-output name=version::$(node -v)"
    
          - name: Cache node_modules
            uses: actions/cache@v3.2.1
            id: node_modules
            with:
              path: |
                **/node_modules
              key: ${{ runner.os }}-node_modules-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}-${{ steps.node.outputs.version }}
    
          - name: Install dependencies
            if: steps.node_modules.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' # Only run if cache miss
            run: npm ci
    
          - run: |
             touch .env
             echo "${{ secrets.ENV }}" > .env
```