# Deprecation warning when installing nodejs on docker container using nodesource install script

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, deprecation-warning

I used to install nodejs on Debian based container using the following in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get upgrade -yq && apt-get install -yq curl git nano
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - 
RUN apt-get install nodejs -y
```

But I recently started getting the following message:

```
    => [base 3/7] RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
                               SCRIPT DEPRECATION WARNING
    ================================================================================ 
TO AVOID THIS WAIT MIGRATE THE SCRIPT Continuing in 60 seconds (press Ctrl-C to abort) ...
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Check the official Node Dockerfile that is used to build the official image available in docker-hub. 
https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/20/bullseye/Dockerfile

Comment: I found that **this is actually simply a matter of the version number to be installed**. I bumped 16 to 20 and the warning disappeared. Check this page for the `CURRENT` or `ACTIVE` version to be installed: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions?tab=readme-ov-file#nodejs-release-calendar

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The notice from the [script](https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x) is

```
  This script, located at https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_X, used to
  install Node.js is deprecated now and will eventually be made inactive.

  Please visit the NodeSource distributions Github and follow the
  instructions to migrate your repo.
  https://github.com/nodesource/distributions 

  The NodeSource Node.js Linux distributions GitHub repository contains
  information about which versions of Node.js and which Linux distributions
  are supported and how to install it.
  https://github.com/nodesource/distributions
```

The [instructions on github](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) amount to a Dockerfile `RUN`

```
FROM docker.io/debian:12-slim
RUN set -uex; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg; \
    mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings; \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key \
     | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg; \
    NODE_MAJOR=18; \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" \
     > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list; \
    apt-get -qy update; \
    apt-get -qy install nodejs;
```

The `docker.io/node:18` image maintained by the Node.js project is Debian based if you want to save some time.

```
FROM docker.io/node:18-bookworm-slim
```

Comment: Isn't it better to chain these commands with `&&` rather than `;` because we don't want a command to run unless all previous commands have succeeded?

Comment: `set -e` achieves the same.

Comment: Ah, I learned something today, thanks.

Comment: Doing this installs `/usr/bin/node` but not `/usr/bin/npm`. Is there a way to make the above install the latter?

Comment: `/usr/bin/npm` should be symlinked to `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm` with just the above nodesource `nodejs` deb.

Answer (score 12):

According to [nodesource/distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) GitHub repository

> Installation Scripts: The installation scripts setup_XX.x are no longer supported and are not needed anymore, as the installation process is straightforward for any RPM and DEB distro.

So, to install node.js you can use the new way as explainded [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debian-and-ubuntu-based-distributions)

> ## Installation Instructions Node.js
>
> `If you're root, you could just ommit the sudo`
>
> ### Download and import the Nodesource GPG key
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg
> sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings  
> curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
> ```
>
> ### Create deb repository
>
> ```
> NODE_MAJOR=20  
> echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
> ```
>
> `Optional: NODE_MAJOR can be changed depending on the version you need.`
>
> ```
> NODE_MAJOR=16  
> NODE_MAJOR=18  
> NODE_MAJOR=20
> ```
>
> ### Run Update and Install
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
> ```

Or you can use the official docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want version 18 and your system uses `DEB` packages, you can install it like this:

```bash
curl -L https://deb.nodesource.com/nsolid_setup_deb.sh | bash -s -- 18
apt-get install nodejs -y
```

Or, if your system uses `RPM` packages:

```bash
curl -L https://rpm.nodesource.com/nsolid_setup_rpm.sh | bash -s -- 18
yum install nodejs -y --setopt=nodesource-nodejs.module_hotfixes=1
```

Source: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-scripts

Answer (score 1):

based on instructions [here's](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/)

```
 # updating nodejs
    RUN set -uex \
        && apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg \
        && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings \
        && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key \
         | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg \
        && NODE_MAJOR=18 \
        && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" \
         | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list \
        && apt-get update \
        && apt-get install nodejs -y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use official node image and avoid reinstalling packages from package manager.

Use official node image as follows. (for node 18.x)

```
FROM node:18-bookworm-slim
```

Comment: What if you need both .NET and Nodejs? There is no official image that has both.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. In that case you may use the official Microsoft image for .NET, then install NodeJs on top of that.

Comment: That is what I'm doing