# Installation nvm in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nvm

I have to install nvm on Ubuntu 14.04 for a work and this is the guide that I have to follow:

Installation of nvm globally

1. sudo git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git /opt/nvm
2. sudo mkdir /usr/local/nvm
3. sudo addgroup -system dev
4. sudo chown -R root:dev /usr/local/nvm
5. sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/local/nvm
6. sudo vim /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh

Installation of node v 4.x

7. sudo mkdir /usr/local/node
8. sudo chown -R root:dev /usr/local/node
9. sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/local/node
10. nvm stable

The problems are that in the passage 6 I don't know exactly what to do or write in the file nvm.sh and then the last command tells me "nvm: command not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add to nvm.sh the following content:

```
export NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm
source /opt/nvm/nvm.sh

export NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/usr/local/node
export PATH="/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH"
```

refer also to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542846/nvm-node-js-recommended-install-for-all-users)

Comment: I had read this answer but if I make `nvm install 0.10` I get `nvm: command not found`

Comment: Try all the commands that i stated directly in the console than try to execute **nvm install**

Comment: now it seems to work but if I close and then reopen the console I get back `nvm: command not found` (and I have to execute all command again)

Comment: Files in /etc/profile.d/ are run when a user logs in (unless you've modified /etc/profile to not do this) and are generally used to set environment variables. Try to restart the system as last instance.

Comment: no, unfortunally it doesn't work. I still have to execute all previous commands

Comment: yeah, now it works. For example if I restart the console and I do `nvm source` I get `Node Version Manager... etc...` and the rest of the help

Comment: Perfect @Carlo! Please mark the question as answered ;-)