# Ubuntu: should I install NVM globally or per single user?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, nvm

I've got a Ubuntu 14.04 server and one user per app.
I wanted to use NVM to manage node versions for every user, but should it be installed globally or one per user?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19040346/1498118), [here](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2014/05/07/ubuntu-install-node-ver%C2%ADsion-man%C2%ADager-globally-for-all-users/#comments) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps) they install NVM globally and then hack it somehow.
However [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542846/nvm-node-js-recommended-install-for-all-users#comment-58129097) says NVM has been created for a single user installation.

Who is right? What's best practice?

Answer (score 3):

After a while of trying both configuration the correct way is to install it per single user. Anyway it still not as straight forward as one might think.

[Read this thread](https://github.com/koenpunt/capistrano-nvm/issues/18#issuecomment-225830550) to see how I had setup my configuration.